# After changing the theme to MaterialComponent default EditTextPreference buttons now with white text

Tags: android, android-styles, material-components-android

My `styles.xml`

```
<style name="AppTheme" parent="Theme.MaterialComponents.DayNight"><!-- MaterialComponents theme -->
    <item name="colorPrimary">@color/colorPrimary</item>
    <item name="colorPrimaryDark">@color/colorPrimaryDark</item>
    <item name="colorAccent">@color/colorAccent</item>
</style>
```

My `preferences.xml`

```
<PreferenceScreen xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto">
    <!-- Default EditTextPreference created by default -->
    <EditTextPreference
        app:key="signature"
        app:title="@string/signature_title"
        app:useSimpleSummaryProvider="true" />
</PreferenceScreen>
```

Result (white text on buttons)

[image]

Empty new project. `com.google.android.material:material:1.1.0`

How to fix text color on EditTextPreference buttons?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As it turned out in version 1.1.0 text color is taken from `colorPrimary`, not from `colorAccent`.

Details: https://github.com/material-components/material-components-android/issues/1009#issuecomment-585285178

---

Workaround: just use style `Theme.MaterialComponents.DayNight.Bridge`

Details: https://material.io/develop/android/docs/getting-started/#bridge-themes